# Not able to generate word cloud from a pandas data frame column with 250k values (non unique, including a lot of blanks)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis, word-cloud

[image]'Hi,

I have a column which has a total of 250K non unique values. I'm simply reading the excel file and
then trying to create a wordcloud. I'm getting a weird output. The column I'm analyzing has a lot of empty cells which I manually changed to BLANK in the code'

```
#Code
data = pd.read_excel('check raw data + doubts data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
wordcloud = WordCloud(
                          background_color='white',
                          stopwords=stopwords,
                          max_words=200,
                          max_font_size=40, 
                          random_state=42
                         ).generate(str(data['Final G/L Account Description_uncleaned']))

print(wordcloud)
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
fig.savefig("word1.png", dpi=900)
```

Please have a look at the output in the attached image. I'm not sure what is happening here

Comment: Did you try adding 'blank' to the stopwords?

Comment: instead of `str(data["Final G/L...."])` try: `" ".join(data.loc[data["Final G/L...] != "Blank", "Final G/L..."])`

Comment: Hi, if you do `str(data['Final G/L Account Description_uncleaned'])` you create the string representation of a pandas series. This contains the `dtype` info and the name of the series (which is the column name). I would recommend to do two things. First, check the output of `data['Final G/L Account Description_uncleaned']`. Does it really contain the strings you want to consider? 2. instead of `str(...)`, I would try `data['Final G/L Account Description_uncleaned'].str.cat(sep=', ')`.

Comment: @jottbe tried your approach and it worked, thanks a lot :) One more question - my word cloud is showing two entries with 'Blank' with the same size - ideally, the words in the word cloud should be unique right? There a few other words which are showing 2-3 times in the word cloud too with the same frequency, any idea what's happening?

My column has cells with multiple words separated by space

Comment: Are there maybe any special characters in your dataframe, which are not recognized?

Comment: @jottbe thanks for your response i checked the data. There are no special characters, i printed the corpus of words after conactenating all cells, what i saw is that there are multiple words

It is coming something like this :
'[ Blank, Blank, Blank, ACCOUNTS PAYABLE - CONVERSION ACCOUNT, ACCOUNTS PAYABLE - CONVERSION ACCOUNT, ACCOUNTS PAYABLE - CONVERSION ACCOUNT, ACCOUNTS PAYABLE - CONVERSION ACCOUNT, ACCOUNTS PAYABLE - CONVERSION ACCOUNT ]'